# Viewing python errors in python console in RStudio with reticulate package

Tags: rstudio, reticulate

I'm trying to understand more about how errors/traceback is printed in Rstudio using the reticulate package.  For example,

```
two_regions['business_day'] = pd.to_datetime(two_regions['business_day'], unit = 'D')
```

returns a ValueError b/c `business_day` is a string.  But nothing returns in the python console.  It's only when I exit and run `py_last_error()` that I can see the traceback and diagnose the problem.  It makes my workflow in reticulate very laborious.  Am I missing something?  Can someone explain why SOME errors will print and others don't?  I cannot find good documentation on this.

Thank you!